# JQuery changing data attribute of <object>

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Works perfectly in FF (as you'd expect) but for some reason when I do this:

```
$('#objectname').attr('data', 'newcontent.php')
```

...absolutely nothing happens in IE.

When I do an

```
alert($('#objectname').attr('data', 'newcontent.php'))
```

it shows the new data source but doesn't change it...

Any ideas please?

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, so I'll just comment: perhaps you need to reload the object in IE to get the new data parameter to take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `data` is a valid HTML attribute. Did you mean to use the jQuery [`data()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Data) function?

```
$('#objectname').data('name','value');
```

*Update for 9/2014* — This question and answer is over five years old now, and isn't really relevant any more. [`data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) is now a valid attribute. I'm leaving my original answer for historical purposes though.

Comment: This page: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml  says data is now a valid HTML attr in HTML5

Comment: This is an old thread by @Alisso is right.  The Data Attribute was valid even prior to html5

Comment: Data is a valid attribute of the object tag. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. Our solution was to re-set the innerHtml of the parent node. With this (ugly) hack IE picks up the changed data attribute and renders accordingly.

```
html = val.parentNode.innerHTML;
val.parentNode.innerHTML = html;
```